# Input text changes an integer? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am making a small AS3 function of the Collatz conjecture.
This is the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var numb:int=0
var amount:int=0
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonclick)
function buttonclick(buttonclicked:MouseEvent):void{
    numb=int(input.text)
    trace(numb)
    amount=0
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, equate)
function equate(equate:Event):void{
    dynam.text=amount.toString() + "\n" + numb.toString();;
    if(numb !=0 && numb !=1){
        if(numb % 2 == 0){
            numb=numb/2
            amount+=1
        }
        else{
            numb=numb*3+1
            amount+=1
        }
    }
}
```

However, sometimes the textinput becomes a negative number.

123123123123 turns into -1430928461

12312312312321312 turns into -1715645152

And so on.

I do not know why, but I think it has to do with

```
numb=int(input.text)
```

But I do not want to do absolute value, because then the equation would make the wrong results.
If you want it to stop on the negative number (and test it yourself) do this:

```
if(numb !=0 && numb !=1 && numb>1)
```

Instead of

```
if(numb !=0 && numb !=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 12312312312321312 turns into -1715645152

That amount of digits won't fit into [**integer**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html) data type. Replace each **`int`** with [**`Number`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html) and test again.

ie : `var numb:Number=0;` and `var amount:Number=0;` and `numb=Number(input.text);`